# How to get a multiple data attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I need your help in this topic
i have the html code :

```
<ul data-role="rows">
<li data-name="member">member X</li>
<li data-name="question">question X</li>
</ul>
<ul data-role="other">
<li data-name="oth">...</li>
...
</ul>
```

I need to get data-name values where data-role = rows
which means i need to get these values : "member" and "question"

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just target those elements, and `map` back the data attributes

```
var names = $('[data-role=rows] [data-name]').map(function(_,el){
    return $(el).data('name');
}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofcqgoe2/)

Comment: it returned this in the console when i tried to log "names" : [prevObject: b.fn.b.init[8], context: document]